How can an ADO environment configure its deployment pipeline?
I have an ADO deployment pipeline.
For each deployment I create an ADO Environment, and then when I run the pipeline I select which Environment I want it to run for.
This way the Environment tracks what has been deployed where.
How do I configure a variable for the Environment that can be used in the pipeline to control the deployment?
For example. I might create one Environment called QA and another called Prod. When the pipeline is run for the QA environment I want a low-grade version of the deployment created, when I run the deployment against the Prod environment I want a highly performant version of the deployment created.
The obvious place to configure this would be in the environment itself. How do I do this?

UPDATE
I have one pipeline for building, and a separate pipeline for deployment. My deployment pipeline triggers automatically for my QA environment, and I trigger it manually to update my production environments.
The environment to be deployed is passed in using a variable like so:
parameters:
- name: ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  type: string
  default: qa

# Lot's of other stuff here

- stage: DeployBuildStage
    jobs:
    - deployment: DeployBuild
      environment: ${{ parameters.ENVIRONMENT_NAME }}


Since the whole purpose of the Environment is to track the state of different deployments, I would also like it to manage the configuration of those deployments. E.g. different hardware for qa, test and prod deployments.
However. Despite the fact that the whole point of the Environment is to manage the different deployments, I don't see any way to associate any configuration with the Environment that I can use in the pipeline to do that.
The only thing I seem to be able to do with an Environment is to create either a VM or a Kubenetes cluster, which is uttlerly useless for my requirements.

The best I have come up with so far is this solution using a variable group.
I create an environment for my deployment.
Then I create a variable group with the same name as the environment, and in that variable group I create whatever variables I need to govern the deployment of the environment. In this example my variable group contains a variable named HARDWARE_GRADE.
I pass the environment into my deploy script using a parameter, then within the deploy script I retrieve the variable group using the name of the environment and use the variables however I need to.
Here is the deployment script.
parameters:
- name: ENVIRONMENT_NAME
  type: string
  default: terraformappservice1-qa

variables:
  - group: ${{ parameters.ENVIRONMENT_NAME }}

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: DeployInfraStage

  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployInfrastructure
    environment: ${{ parameters.ENVIRONMENT_NAME }}

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - powershell: |
              echo "HARDWARE_GRADE: $(HARDWARE_GRADE)"
            displayName: Display Environment

It seems to work ok. It's a bit more work and a few more moving parts than is ideal for something that I think should be supported directly by the environment though.

Since you are using Environments, you are currently using the YAML Pipeline in Azure DevOps.

How do I configure a variable for the Environment that can be used in the pipeline to control the deployment?

To meet your requirement, I suggest that you can use the Parameters and IF expression in YAML Pipeline to select the target environment.
Update:
Based on your updated details, the configurations are different between different environments, and you also need to manage the environment configurations.
You can use YAML template in YAML Pipeline to manage the configuration of different environments.
You can name the template yaml file name after the environment name.
Here is an example:
QA-template.yml
stages:
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    environment:
      name: 'QA'
      resourceName: VM0
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo xx

PROD-template.yml
stages:
- stage: deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployWeb
    displayName: deploy Web App
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    environment:
      name: 'PROD'
      resourceName: VM0
      resourceType: virtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - script: echo Hello world

Main YAML:
parameters:
- name: Environmentname
  type: string
  default: QA
  values:
   - QA
   - PROD

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest


stages:
- template: ${{ parameters.Environmentname }}-template.yml

When you add new release environment, you can add new template yaml in the repo based on environment configuration. Then you can add option in yaml parameters to select the target template to run pipeline.

I don't want to hard-code in my deployment script which style of deployment should be used for each environment. That would be horribly inflexible. Each time I release a new environment I would have to edit and retest my deployment script. Surely the whole point of environments being defined as top level entities in ADO is so you can administer them independently of your build and deploy artifacts.

@Neutrino Do you mean you don't want to hardcode the environment name in your YAML code? If so, Pipeline will not recognize the environments name you need to use. I think that this is required.

It's not required to hardcode the Environment name in the YAML. Please see the update to my question.

@Neutrino Thanks for your update. I can understand your requirement better. You need to manage the environment and the corresponding configuration in the pipeline. I suggest you use yaml template. Check my update in the answer. Feel free to let me know if it can be closer to your needs.

This approach still has the same problem. Our pipelines enable us to deploy new environments and clone existing environments quickly and flexibly. This greatly improves our productivity and makes our testing more robust. Commits to the codebase on the other hand go through an approval process. If we have to edit our codebase, and thus go through code review, simply to deploy a new environment, then that drastically reduces the efficiency of our devops process.
So how can I add configuration to an Environment without having to edit the codebase and hard-code it there?

Atm I'm thinking that creating a variable group with the same name as the Environment and retrieving that inside the pipeline might work. But it seems a bit clunky and not very joined up for something that I would expect to be supported without requiring hacky workarounds.

If you don't want to add the template to the current repo, you may consider create a new empty repo to save the template files. And use repo resource in YAML pipeline to use the yaml template. As far as I know, there is no other way to connect environment and configuration except using template to simplify YAML and improve efficiency.

The environment select step will do at compile time. And the Variable Group will expand at runtime. In this case, the environment field will not get the correct value if you use the variable group. This  should be the limitation

@Neutrino It sounds like you have a process problem. Perhaps you can have a different PR policy for the path containing your pipeline template files so that you can have an expedited review without the red tape that's slowing you down?
